# ASP.NET MVC - Data not appearing on list view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two tables

```
COUNTRIES
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }

STATES
public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View();
        IEnumerable<BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.BPPCCSPAdminStatesService.STATES> states = _statesService.GetStates().Where(opt => opt.ACTION_STATUS != 2);

        return View(states);
    }
```

**View**

```
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATE_CODE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATE_NAME)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME)
            </td>
```

[image]

From the diagram, the Country Name is not appearing. It is COUNTRY_ID in STATES, taking its root from COUNTRY_NAME in COUNTRIES.

> Please why is the Country Name blank

Comment: What does `_statesService.GetStates()` returns and how does it do it (what code) ?

Comment: Its Populates from the STATES Models model STATE_ID, STATE_CODE, COUNTRY_ID